# Developing R package when functions are written in S4 and using roxygen2

Tags: r, package, r-s4, devtools, roxygen2

I took the following code from [An R Companion to Applied Regression - Chapter 8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/141297514X). Everything works fine except the `R` code written in `S4`. When I'm building the documentation, I'm getting `lreg5-class.Rd` rather than `lreg5.Rd` and could not get `lreg5` function. This is my first attempt to build an `R` package.

### lreg5 Function

```
#' An S4 class to Logistic Regression.
#'
#' @export
#'  
#' @slot coefficients Coefficients
#' @slot var Variance Covariance Matrix
#' @slot deviance Deviance
#' @slot predictors Predictors of the model
#' @slot iterations No of iterations for convergence

setClass(
   Class = "lreg5"
 , slots =  list(
        coefficients="numeric"
      , var="matrix"
      , deviance="numeric"
      , predictors="character"
      , iterations="numeric"
     )
  )


lreg5 <-
  function(X, y, predictors=colnames(X), max.iter=10,
        tol=1E-6, constant=TRUE, ...) {
    if (!is.numeric(X) || !is.matrix(X))
        stop("X must be a numeric matrix")
    if (!is.numeric(y) || !all(y == 0 | y == 1))
        stop("y must contain only 0s and 1s")
    if (nrow(X) != length(y))
        stop("X and y contain different numbers of observations")
    if (constant) {
        X <- cbind(1, X)
        colnames(X)[1] <- "Constant"
    }
    b <- b.last <- rep(0, ncol(X))
    it <- 1
    while (it <= max.iter){
        p <- as.vector(1/(1 + exp(-X %*% b)))
        var.b <- solve(crossprod(X, p * (1 - p) * X))
        b <- b + var.b %*% crossprod(X, y - p)
        if (max(abs(b - b.last)/(abs(b.last) + 0.01*tol)) < tol) break
        b.last <- b
        it <- it + 1
    }
    if (it > max.iter) warning("maximum iterations exceeded")
    dev <- -2*sum(y*log(p) + (1 - y)*log(1 - p))
    result <- new("lreg5", coefficients=as.vector(b), var=var.b,
        deviance=dev, predictors=predictors, iterations=it)
    result
}

setMethod("show", signature(object="lreg5"),
    definition=function(object) {
            coef <- object@coefficients
            names(coef) <- object@predictors
            print(coef)
        }
    )


setMethod("summary", signature(object="lreg5"),
    definition=function(object, ...) {
            b <- object@coefficients
            se <- sqrt(diag(object@var))
            z <- b/se
            table <- cbind(b, se, z, 2*(1-pnorm(abs(z))))
            colnames(table) <- c("Estimate", "Std.Err", "Z value", "Pr(>z)")
            rownames(table) <- object@predictors
            printCoefmat(table)
            cat("\nDeviance =", object@deviance,"\n")
        }
    )
```

---

### Packaging

```
# Step 0: Packages you will need
library(devtools)
library(roxygen2)

# Step 1: Create your package directory
setwd("WD")

create("PackageName")


# Step 2: Add functions

# Step 3: Add documentation

# Step 4: Process your documentation
setwd("./PackageName")
devtools::document()

# Step 5: Install!
setwd("..")
#load_all("PackageName")
devtools::install("PackageName")

# Stp 6: Load the Package!
library(PackageName)
help(PackageName)
```

Answer (score 4):

A few tips:

- first of all, put your class definitions and your functions in different files. This will help roxygen get everything in the right .Rd document
- second, use an editor that helps you in the process. I'm very happy using RStudio, as it has all building tools (including `roxygen2`) incorporated. Take a look at the [documentation of RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/sections/200130627-Package-Development) for more info.
- third, there are no `roxygen2` commands in the code you show here. You need to do at least a bit of effort. The roxygen system allows you to comment your functions in the .R file itself and generate the help files based on these comments. But without comments, you're not going to generate much.

A bit more specific:

You can define which information is going to which .Rd file with the roxygen tag `@rdname`. I use this if I want to group some things in one file, but spread the information over different .Rd files. Another option is `@describeIn`, which is introduced more recently. This latter tag allows you to specify in which .Rd file a certain function/class/... has to be described.

For more information, see this [vignette on creating .Rd files using `roxygen2`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html)

I strongly suggest you take a look at the different vignettes to get some ideas. Documenting S4 classes and methods using `roxygen2` isn't as trivial as one would desire, but it's definitely doable. For an example, take a look at eg the Bioconductor package `unifiedWMWqPCR`. I've worked on that one and use `roxygen2` for the S4-based package. The source can be downloaded from following link:

http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/unifiedWMWqPCR.html

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Joris for your nice tips and advise. I do have `roxygen2` commands in my code but just removed to save the space here. I've downloaded the package you mentioned. Could you guide me why am I getting `lreg5-class.Rd` rather than `lreg5.Rd` and why my `lreg5` function is not working here. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 I can't guide you without seeing the roxygen tags. I don't know if you export the `lreg5` function correctly for example, which would explain why you might think it's not working (it's simply not visible from the workspace). The `xxx-class.Rd` is the standard and preferred way to name .Rd files that describe classes. Exactly to keep them out of the way of .Rd files that describe functions with the same name. Go through the documentation thoroughly again, I have the feeling you misunderstand some important basics here.

Comment: I've edited the question and included the `roxygen2` commands and would highly appreciate if you help me. Thanks

Comment: As I thought, you don't export the lreg5 function. You have to export that from the namespace, otherwise the user can't find the function from the workspace. See eg http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html

Comment: I'm getting frustrate with this. I tried with putting `@export` as `roxygen2` command but still couldn't figure out. I'd highly appreciate if you help me to at least get start with this. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 Start with putting the function lreg5 in a separate file instead of in the class definition. Then take a look at http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ , the help pages by Hadley Wickham. I can't help you here, as this depends on your description file, your namespace file and the likes. But it would help if you add the tag `@export` right above the function you're exporting.

Answer (score 2):

@Joris has said most of this already, but perhaps I can help clarify. You have both a class **and** a function called `lreg5` in this example. You must export the class **and** the function if you want both of them to be seen. In your sample code only the class is documented and exported. It is a class, so roxygen2 is clever enough to give it the name lreg5-class, which is why you get a file called `man/lreg5-class.Rd`.

To fix the problem you report, add something like this to your code (I have put a full sample repository here: https://github.com/jefferis/lreg which shows the significant steps along the way.)

```
#' carry out regression
#' @param X,y inputs
#' @param predictors defaults to \code{colnames(x)}
#' @param max.iter maximum number of iterations (default: 10)
#' @param tol tolerance
#' @param constant add a constant
#' @param ... Additional arguements (currently ignored)
#' @export
#' @return an object of class lreg5
#' @seealso \code{\link{lreg5-class}}
#' @examples
#' lreg5(X=matrix(rnorm(3*100),ncol=3, dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:3])), 
#'       y=sample(0:1,100, replace=TRUE))

lreg5 <-function(X, y, predictors=colnames(X), max.iter=10,
        tol=1E-6, constant=TRUE, ...) {
## rest of function definition ...
}
```

The @export tag in this block is the crucial bit, although you will need to document the function arguments and give a title; examples are also a good way to ensure that the function is actually exported and works. Now you will see that you have a file called `man/lreg5.Rd` and the `lreg5` function will be available.

Note that as far as I know there, is no need to put the lreg5 function and the lreg5 class definition+methods in different source code files – though this may help to organise things better.